# How do I get my address to appear at the top of contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts

The scenario is that I've moved six times in the last six years, and can never remember my home number. (Let alone the postcode of my PO Box.) So I have to look it up all the time.

In one of the iOS updates (9.0.1?) - my address was displayed at the top of the Contacts - so I could jump straight to it. Then it went away again.

I'd like this feature back. I'm sure there must be a setting.

My question is: **How do I get my address to appear at the top of contacts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a contact for yourself with the home address, phone number, etc. To do this, create a contact with your information like any other contact. Then, go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, & Calendars. Scroll down to "My Info," and select the contact you just created. [image]

Then, your contact card will appear at the top of the Contacts list every time.